# Physics body scaling in Corona SDK

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk

i need to write a code whichs scales the object after it goes through 500 px, i made this code but it doesnt work:

```
function localScale( event )
  if self.y > 500 then
    self.scale(1.10, 1.10)
  end
end
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should give

```
self:scale(1.10,1.10)
```

Or you can give

```
self.scale(self,1.10,1.10)
```

Also, I think when scaling Physics bodies, only the image is scaled. The Physics body is not scaled.  So bear that in mind!